# Si decimos "segundo", ¿por qué no decimos "primo" en vez de "minuto"?

Tags: etimología, historia, sustantivos, tiempo

A la hora de dividir tanto las horas como los grados, decimos *[minuto](https://dle.rae.es/?id=PL6TXXC)* a la primera subdivisión en 60 partes, el cual deriva de la misma palabra latina de la que deriva *menudo*, mientras que a la segunda subdivisión sí que se la denomina *[segundo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=XTUS1jC)*. ¿Por qué se dice pues *minuto* y no *primo* o *primero*?

Answer (score 7):

Esto en realidad es común a muchos idiomas, tanto descendientes del latín como otros que no pero que han adoptado los términos latinos. La explicación se puede leer tanto en [la Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minuto) como en otras fuentes tales como [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/minute). Aunque tampoco está de más dejarlo aquí escrito.

Básicamente todo se remonta al astrónomo y matemático [Claudio Ptolomeo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claudio_Ptolomeo). En sus investigaciones decidió denominar a las subdivisiones del grado *pars minuta prima* y a las de estas *pars minuta secunda*, que literalmente significan "parte menuda primera" y "parte menuda segunda".

En el primer caso, de "minuta prima" lo que prevaleció fue el concepto de que se trataba de una "parte pequeña" (menuda), por lo que la voz que prevaleció fue *minuta* y que, al contrario que ocurrió con *menudo*, al ser un concepto científico poco usado en el habla común apenas evolucionó en su pronunciación. De hecho el primer caso que encuentro en el CORDE es de un texto escrito entre 1381 y 1418, titulado *Sevillana medicina de Juan de Aviñón*:

> *[...] ca el altura del sol es en Seuilla en treynta y siete grados: & treynta minutos [...].*

En el segundo caso, el concepto que prevaleció fue el hecho de que era una segunda subdivisión de una parte que ya era pequeña de por sí, por lo que *secunda* fue la voz que se acabó usando para denominarla, que evolucionó a *segundo* a la par que sus otras acepciones.